# When creating my own data structure, should I use iterators or indices to provide access from the outside?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, iterator

Suppose I'm writing a project in a modern version of C++ (say 11 or 14) and use STL in that project. At a certain moment, I need to program a specific data structure that can be built using STL containers. The DS is encapsulated in a class (am I right that encapsulating the DS in a class is the only correct way to code it in C++?), thus I need to provide some sort of interface to provide read and/or write access to the data. Which leads us to the question:

Should I use (1a) iterators or (1b) simple "indices" (i.e. numbers of a certain type) for that? The DS that I'm working on right now is pretty much linear, but then when the elements are removed, of course simple integer indices are going to get invalidated. That's about the only argument against this approach that I can imagine.

Which approach is more idiomatic? What are the objective technical arguments for and against each one?

Also, when I choose to use iterators for my custom DS, should I (2a) `public`-ly `typedef` the iterators of the container that is used internally or (2b) create my own iterator from scratch? In the open libraries such as Boost, I've seen custom iterators being written from scratch. On the other hand, I feel I'm not able to write a proper iterator yet (i.e. one that is as detailed and complex as the ones in STL and/or Boost).

**Edit** as per @πάντα ῥεῖ request:

*I've asked myself this question with a few DS in a few projects while studying at the Uni, but here's the last occurrence that made me come here and ask.*

The DS is meant to represent a triangle array, or vertex array, or whatever one might call it. Point is, there are two arrays or lists, one storing the vertex coordinates, and another one storing triplets of indices from the first array, thus representing triangles. (This has been coded a gazillion times already, yet I want to write it on my own, once, for the purpose of learning.) Obviously, the two arrays should stay in sync, hence the encapsulation. The set of operations is meant to include adding (maybe also removing) a vertex, adding and removing a triangle (a vertex triplet) using the vertex data from the same array. How I see it is that the client adds vertices, writes down the indices/iterators, and then issues a call to add a triangle based on those indices/iterators, which in turn returns another index/iterator to the resulting triangle.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples how you want to use that please? In general I'd say providing iterators would have more advantage for using your stuff with the standard c++ algorithms.

Comment: also iterators might get invalidated when you erase elements from a container

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've asked myself this question with a few DS already, so I'll just describe the last occasion which has made me come here and finally ask a question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ see above, edited, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @iksemyonov How does this edit satisfy my request actually? I've been asking for (pseudo-) code samples.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm in the design phase, so there's no real code yet. Do the verbal descriptions of the desired operations maybe sound ambiguous so that they need to be replaced with pseudocode?

Comment: @iksemyonov _"I'm in the design phase, so there's no real code yet."_ Sounds like your question better fits for Programmers SE then. The [tag:c++] tag clearly requires you to ask questions about concrete code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I'm well aware of that, may be that question should be handled in the same manner as [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/318076/fine-tuning-details-in-c-function-for-different-customers) was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I don't see why you couldn't get both, if this makes sense for your container.

`std::vector` has iterators and the `at`/`operator[]` methods to provide access with indexes.

The API of your container depends on the operations you want to make available to your clients.

- Is the container iterable, i.e. is it possible to iterate over each elements? Then, you should provide an iterator.
- Does it make sense to randomly access elements in your container, knowing their address? Then you can also provide the `at(size_t)`/`operator[size_t]` methods.
- Does it make sense to randomly access elements in your container,
  knowing a special "key"? The you should probably provide the `at(key_type)`/`operator[key_type]` methods.

---

As for your question regarding custom iterators or reuse of existing iterators:

If your container is basically a wrapper that adds some insertion/removal logic to an existing container, I think it is fine to publicly typedef the existing iterator, as a custom iterator may miss some features of the the existing iterator, may contain bugs, and will not add any significant feature over the existing iterator.

On the other hand, if you iterate in a non-standard fashion (for instance, I implemented once a `recursive_unordered_map` that accepted a parent `recursive_unordered_map` at construction and would iterate both on its own `unordered_map` and on its parent's (and its parent's parent's...). I had to implement a custom iterator for this.

Answer (score 2):

> Which approach is more idiomatic?

Using iterators is definitely the way to go. Functions in `<algorithm>` don't work with indices. They work with iterators. If you want your container to be enabled for use by the functions in `<algorithm>`, using iterators is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is recommended that the class offers its own iterator. Under the hood, it could be an index or a STL iterator (preferred). But, as long as external clients and public APIs are concerned, they only deal with the iterator offered by the class.

Example 1

```
  class Dictionary {
    private:
      typedef std::unordered_map<string, string> DictType;
    public:
      typedef DictType::iterator DictionaryIterator;
  };
```

Example 2

```
  class Sequence {
    private:
      typedef std::vector<string> SeqType;
    public:
      struct SeqIterator {
        size_t index;
        SeqIterator operator++();
        string operator*();
      };
  };
```

If the clients are operating solely on `SeqIterator`, then the above can later be modified to

```
  class Sequence {
    private:
      typedef std::deque<string> SeqType;
    public:
      typedef SeqType::iterator SeqIterator;
  };
```

without the clients getting affected.

Comment: I don't think a `size_t` can ever be used as an "iterator".